# Not all properties visible in Visual Studio IntelliSense for UIAutomation's AutomationElement class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, microsoft-ui-automation

[The docs page for AutomationElement class at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement?view=netframework-4.7.2) indicates that the class has six properties.  In my Visual Studio C# solution, IntelliSense shows only four; *FocusedElement* and *RootElement* are missing.  When I look at the metadata, the properties are listed, so that tells me the documentation is not out-of-date:

[image]

I tried it in the Immediate window, and the result is the same, showing only four out of six properties:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?  If not, why is this happening?

I am on Windows 10 Professional using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise with the latest build.

Comment: Are you creating `new object` of this class ?!

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi Yes, as follows: `_aeTargetDocument = _aeTargetWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, _findControl);`

Comment: Well, These two missing properties are `static` and they are not accessible by the class object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two missing properties are `static` and they are not accessible by the class object.